# Who control Google Cloud platform filtering?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it Google or the client can control the firewall and block IP's ?

Because we are in Sudan and we can't access Khan Academy website, we got "error 403 forbidden", and we should visit this website because of the economic US sanction to Sudan is lifted for all personal communication tools and that's include mobile stores and learning platforms.

It's effective since February 18, 2015, check the Treasury.gov website for more details:

http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/OFAC-Enforcement/Pages/20150217_33.aspx

So, who control Google Cloud platform filtering ?

See the screen shot :

[image]

Comment: IPs can also be controlled by Government of a country by DNS so basically blocks can be placed from anywhere on your lan to incoming requests at Google (though unlikely to be at Google as they would welcome as much traffic as possible for advertising).

Comment: Yes sure, in Sudan, the blocked websites redirected to this ..

http://imgur.com/YTCcOKs

Comment: Hmm, there is no question that the site is up accessing from the UK. I would ignore what is actually served - DNS can repoint to any machine which can serve up a copy of a site. What are your VPN options to re-route access from another country ?

Comment: I can access the website without any problem using all VPN's services available out there, but that's not the solution, I would like to know who control the platform, is it a normal web-hosting and the client can control it? or just Google can ? we need to contact them to report this technical issue, I already contact "Khan Academy" and they didn't figure it out, and Google suggest to contact and help be through stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest doing routing checks eg from a linux based machine terminal (or mac with these tools installed using brew):

```
mtr khanacademy.org
```

which at the last hop is blocked by their router for ICMP - giving '?' (ask to unblock temporarily) but goes to 205.251.244.195 as the network point prior to this.

Also do a whois:

```
whois khanacademy.org
```

giving a postal code 94042 which is Mountain View CA - I think the same as Google.

Unexpected, though they do hosting is that

```
whois 205.251.244.195
```

shows to be Amazon